# ThreadStart, field initializer cannot reference the non-static field

Tags: c#, multithreading, mouseclick-event

I am trying to use Threads in my app but i get a error. I searched a solution at MSDN and other forums but i didn't get it.

```
public class ClickingThread
    {
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

        public ClickingThread() 
        {
        }

        public void MouseClicking()
        {
            int X = Cursor.Position.X;
            int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, X, Y, 0, 0);
        }

        public void Click()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                MouseClicking();
            }
        }
    }
```

And when i try to use method from this class like this

```
ClickingThread clicker = new ClickingThread();
Thread click = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clicker.Click));
```

I get an error (second line -> `clicker.Click`)"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method etc."

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: Thread click = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clicker.Click)); exactly clicker.Click is underline at red

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `new Thread`?

Comment: The code you show works for me....

Comment: I use it inside button_Click method but i get error when i create an instance...

Comment: What is the exact error and how does that button_click method look like and what is the name of that form?

Comment: You see Click method in code. It is implemented in ClickingThread class. Error ocurs -> clicker.Click

Comment: No, I don't see it in your code. The code you show works. You need to provide an [mcve] because the issue you see must have a different root cause but I have not enough info to make a guess.

Comment: i cant add whole code, i have problem with formatting. But you can look it here http://wklejto.pl/235962

Comment: Ok when i write static ClickingThread problem gone. Thanks...